# error in res.sendFile command nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, body-parser

[

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/node-demo");
var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
});
var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
    var myData = new User(req.body);
    myData.save()
        .then(item => {
            res.send("Name saved to database");
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("Unable to save to database");
        });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Intro to Node and MongoDB</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Into to Node and MongoDB</h1>
        <form method="post" action="/addname">
            <label>Enter Your Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name..." required>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name..." required>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Name">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

]

**by running the code on localhost:3000**
i'm having that result on my bowser

TypeError: res.sendFile is not a function
   at app.get (C:\Users\DeLL pc\Documents\node\app.js:18:9)
   at callbacks (C:\Users\DeLL pc\Documents\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
   at param (C:\Users\DeLL pc\Documents\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
   at pass (C:\Users\DeLL pc\Documents\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
   at Router._dispatch (C:\Users\DeLL pc\Documents\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:173:5)
   at Object.router [as handle] (C:\Users\DeLL pc\Documents\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
   at next (C:\Users\DeLL pc\Documents\node\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:174:15)
   at Object.urlencodedParser [as handle] (C:\Users\DeLL pc\Documents\node\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:91:7)
   at next (C:\Users\DeLL pc\Documents\node\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:174:15)
   at Object.jsonParser [as handle] (C:\Users\DeLL pc\Documents\node\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:110:7)
   at next (C:\Users\DeLL pc\Documents\node\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:174:15)
   at Object.expressInit [as handle] (C:\Users\DeLL pc\Documents\node\node_modules\express\lib\middleware.js:30:5)
   at next (C:\Users\DeLL pc\Documents\node\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:174:15)
   at Object.query [as handle] (C:\Users\DeLL pc\Documents\node\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\query.js:43:5)
   at next (C:\Users\DeLL pc\Documents\node\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:174:15)
   at Function.app.handle (C:\Users\DeLL pc\Documents\node\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:182:3)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I know of for `res` to exist, but `res.sendFile()` to not be a function is if you're running an older version of Express from before the `sendFile` method was added to Express.

From [the doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile):

> res.sendFile() is supported by Express v4.8.0 onwards.

---

You can also add some logging to get you more info:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log(typeof res.sendFile);
    console.log(res);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

From your console, you can see what version of Express you have installed with this command line:

```
npm view express version
```